# Issues with popup in WebView

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

Frustration has finally overcome me and I am reaching out for some assistance. Currently in my app I have a webview that loads a series of pages. On several of the pages there are JS Login popups that appear. If I use a WebChromeClient and just straight open the browser the pages work fine however in my webview I cannot for my life get the popups to appear. I have tried a custom ChromeClient to handle the JS popups. I have also tried dozens of questions and answers on SO to no avail. Essentially is there any way to get the straight functionality of the WebChromeClient but keep it in my fragments webview. Any help would be absurdly appreciated.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_m2_web, container, false);
    web = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.m2webView);

    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewController());
    web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    web.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    web.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    web.loadUrl("myurl");
    web.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web.canGoBack()) {
                web.goBack();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: I am also trying to display Authentication(UserName/Password) popup, when the web page is loaded, but no success!